# Find the smallest natural number which is 4 times smaller than the number written with the same digit but in the reverse order.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question says "Find the smallest natural number which is 4 times smaller than the number written with the same digit but in the reverse order."

I tried to solve it in this way:

New number = 4*(original number)

Thus, new number is a multiple of 4.

SO, its unit diits must be 0,2,4,6,8.
Now, how to proceed after this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also know that the first digit of the original number has to be $2$, which means the last digit must be $8$.  So we have:

$$8\,a\,b\,2=4\cdot(2\,b\,a\,8)$$

(You can check to see that $3$ digit numbers will not work).  It follows that $b$ can only be $0,1,$ or $2$.  If we multiply, we obtain the following equation:

$$4a+3\equiv b\operatorname{mod}10\\$$

From this it follows that $a$ is either $2$ or $7$ and $b=1$.  This leaves only two options, and one of them works.